# Найдите лексические ошибки и укажите их тип.

Tags: лексика

Он понимал, что из этого дна ему не выбраться. Именно Пётр Первый распахнул окно между нашими странами. В силу слабой разработки проекта оценка его преждевременна. Яркая маска плотно укрывала лицо вратаря.

Comment: Только после Вас. Дайте свои варианты.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ошибка употребления предлога: можно находиться "на" дне и подниматься "со" дна, но не "из" него. Дно - поверхность.
   Он понимал, что с этого дна ему не подняться.
   Он понимал, что оказался на дне и возврата нет.
2. А было ли что распахивать, если нынче известно, что "прорубить" пришлось? 
   Не кто иной, как Пётр Первый "прорубил" окно между нашими странами.
3. Ввиду слабой проработки проекта, давать ему оценку преждевременно. 
   (так понятнее, проект критикуют или его оценку).
4. Если была маска была шерстяная она бы "плотно укутывала", вратарская маска могла бы "плотно прилегать", но от этого нет пользы (это ведь не посмертная маска). А "плотно укрывать" может разве что снег.
   Лицо вратаря закрывала ярко раскрашенная маска.